# Application fails to run on Heroku

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

I have NodeJs application with yeoman, grunt, bower installed. I generatedm angularjs app using yeomen. Local version of application runs with no problem by typing `grunt serve`. Moreover application was successfully deployed to Heroku by `grunt deploy` [link](https://gist.github.com/micjamking/9539467). When trying to access application on heroku it shows:

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

In application log (Heroku dashboard > Activity):

Deployed

Build succeeded

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Reading application state
       package.json...
       build directory...
       cache directory...
       environment variables...

       Node engine:         >=0.10.0
       Npm engine:          unspecified
       Start mechanism:     Procfile
       node_modules source: package.json
       node_modules cached: true

       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

-----> Installing binaries
       Resolving node version >=0.10.0 via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 0.10.35...
       Using default npm version: 1.4.28

-----> Building dependencies
       Restoring node modules from cache
       Pruning unused dependencies
       npm WARN package.json nodejsw3@0.0.0 No repository field.
       Installing any new modules
       npm WARN package.json nodejsw3@0.0.0 No repository field.

-----> Checking startup method
       Found Procfile

-----> Finalizing build
       Creating runtime environment
       Exporting binary paths
       Cleaning npm artifacts
       Cleaning previous cache
       Caching results for future builds

-----> Build succeeded!

       nodejsw3@0.0.0 /tmp/build_9b26539892553ae79f16e539e2f083e0
       ????????? (empty)

       WARNING: Avoid semver ranges starting with '>' in engines.node
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 6.8MB
-----> Launching... done, v9
       https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Project structure:

[image]

**Log**

```
2015-02-07T17:49:56.504866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=257d316d-98
d1-4d21-a170-7c27e42b907e fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:49:57.762152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=
f109ba40-e921-486a-a79a-7a7d842705a7 fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:53:40.155437+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=7e0e784c-0e
76-48b1-ad3e-bbf74b400e31 fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:53:41.454002+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=
4d56eacf-5515-48e4-9b5d-34ccc4c4457e fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:54:20.109125+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b244e431-81
d6-4f82-a0e0-1e845a45a449 fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503
 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:54:21.286203+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=
e2c7d762-a88c-49f6-a15b-e1768e7310d5 fwd="10.10.10.11" dyno= connect= service=
 status=503 bytes=
2015-02-07T17:57:14.924093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2015-02-07T17:57:16.809601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
ode index.js`
2015-02-07T17:57:18.731681+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736235+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:338:15)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736237+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:280:25)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736241+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736243+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/ind
ex.js:1:77)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.732015+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736244+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
56:26)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.731200+00:00 app[web.1]:
2015-02-07T17:57:18.732021+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736232+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'

2015-02-07T17:57:18.736239+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:36
4:17)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736246+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:474:10)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:3
2)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736249+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:312:12)
2015-02-07T17:57:18.736251+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (mod
ule.js:497:10)
2015-02-07T17:57:19.580364+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-02-07T17:57:19.592340+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
```

Comment: Can you look at your heroku logs. And paste the stacktrace here

Comment: Looks like you are missing express js dependency. Have you added that in your packages.json?

Comment: I have "express": "~4.9.x" in `bower.json`. Do I have to move it to `package.json`? I don't understand why there is 2 place to hold dependencies....

Comment: Bower.json is for UI dependencies while package.json is for node dependencies. Express is your server it needs to be in package.json.

Comment: Moving dependency to `package.json` solved problem.